# Fill Sheet1 ID with value of ID from Sheet2

Tags: worksheet-function, id

im new here and i have a problem with filling data from another sheet.

Sheet1 looks like this:

```
 _|___A___|___B___|___C___|
 1|   1   |John   |1,35,12|
 2|   2   |Derek  |45,2,1 |
 and so....
```

Sheet2

```
 _|___A___|___B___|
 1|   1   |Hammer |
 2|   2   |Nails  |
        . . .
12|   12  |Car    |
        . . . 
35|   35  |Rope   |
        . . .
45|   45  |Vase   |
```

i need to replace ID's in Sheet1 with names from Sheet2 (separated by "," or ", ") to get this:

```
 _|___A___|___B___|_______C_________|
 1|   1   |John   |Hammer,Rope,Car  |
 2|   2   |Derek  |Vase,Nails,Hammer|
 and so....
```

i dont know if its even possible but if is please help me

ty :)

Comment: 1. What spreadsheet application are you using?  2. Does col C always contain exactly three items?  3. Must the result replace the col C contents on sheet1, or could the solution involve adding a column with the revised content (and hiding col C if needed), or creating a new sheet that looks like your final example?

Comment: 1. excel 2007
2. no... some less, some more
3. it can replace sheet1 or create new sheet that looks like final example.

Answer (score 0):

add this code to new module in excel:

```
Function SplitThenFind(cell As String, sourceColumn As Range)

    Dim myArray As Variant
    Dim element As Variant
    Dim result As String
    Dim findResult As Range

    myArray = Split(cell, ",")

    For Each element In myArray

        Set findResult = Application.Worksheets(sourceColumn.Worksheet.Index).Range(sourceColumn.Address).Find(element, Lookat:=xlWhole)

        If Not (findResult Is Nothing) Then
            ' with offset you can select the column you need
            result = result & findResult.Cells.Offset(0, 1).Value & ","
        End If
    Next

    If Len(result) > 0 Then
      result = Left(result, Len(result) - 1)
    End If

SplitThenFind = result

End Function
```

Comment: can u please explain me how to do it?
i using excel 2007

Comment: I add code to excel module as custom function, look at this good reference: [link](https://www.dummies.com/software/microsoft-office/excel/how-to-create-custom-excel-functions/)